# Is function called every time the for loop runs?

Tags: python

I have a very general doubt and can be applied to many scenarios, If I have a code like this

```
for val in arr.flatten():
   print(val)
```

**Query**

Is flatten() function called every time the for loop runs ?
If so, then above approach will be inefficient compared to this one

```
arr2 = arr.flatten()
for val in arr2:
   print(val)
```

Comment: No, the part after `in` is only evaluated once. But in general, moving code that does not depend on the loop from the body of the loop to outside of the loop can provide speedups in some situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples are equivalent (aside from one additional local variable).

What happens in the first example is:

1. `arr.flatten()` is called, and it returns an iterable (which isn't bound to a name)
2. `for` iterates over the returned iterable.

What happens in the second example is:

1. `arr.flatten()` is called, and it returns an iterable, which is bound to the name `arr2`.
2. `for` iterates over `arr2`.